# How to catch exception in scala.sys.process pipe

Tags: scala

If I download a big file with [`scala.sys.process`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.5/scala/sys/process/index.html) like this:

```
import java.io.File
import java.net.URL
import scala.sys.process._
new URL("http://www.scala-lang.org/") #> new File("scala-lang.html") !
```

If there is some problem during the download, the stack trace will just print at stderr but it is not caught in my try-catch block. I believe there are ways to catch the error and retry, but how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence

```
new URL("http://www.scala-lang.org/") #> new File("scala-lang.html") !
```

evaluates to `Int` which corresponds to the exit code of the operation.

When it equals 0, the result is successful, otherwise there was an error.

So it can be processed as follows

```
val result = new URL(...)
if (result != 0) {
  throw new MyCustomException("message") // or retry
}
```

Comment: HI, just get time to check, it look like it can return no a number, it can return null?

Comment: I think that it must not return `null`, because `Int` and `null` are not compatible in Scala. Since `!` returns an `Int`, the outcome would be either an integer exit code, or an exception.

Comment: Umm... in fact in 2.12 Scala, it return a string, let me keep log it and and see what it contain, usually it is a empty string