# Can I add timeout scala.sys.process pipe

Tags: scala, pipe

It somehow related to [How to catch exception in scala.sys.process pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49614013/how-to-catch-exception-in-scala-sys-process-pipe) that I asked a while back. If I download a big file with scala.sys.process like this:

```
import java.io.File
import java.net.URL
import scala.sys.process._
new URL("http://www.scala-lang.org/") #> new File("scala-lang.html") !
```

There is chance somehow the download never return ( and no exception / return code ) and then block the whole process. Just wonder, can I add some timeout, say an hour, if it don't finish, then having exception ( or fail code? )

Comment: You might find [this here](https://gist.github.com/j-keck/7bd29de3a2d8b2ae6773) inspiring, especially the `proc.destroy()` part.